# Pagecontrol for label in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have view controller which displays some text in the label with scrollview but I want to create a page control for that label meaning that different texts in labels with page control. I have following code for label.

import Foundation
  import UIKit

```
 class tips : UIViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var tipsscroll: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet weak var solutionlabel: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    solutionlabel.text = "Some text"

    solutionlabel.numberOfLines = 0
    solutionlabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
   // solutionlabel.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 14.0)


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create IBOutlet for page controller and Scrollview

```
@IBOutlet weak var pageController: UIPageControl!
@IBOutlet weak var ScrollController: UIScrollView!
```

Create A Array

```
 let pageString = ["showsHorizontalScrollIndicator working pagecontroller", "running christmas card contact in ", "from the application you can back the Address"]
```

Create Delegate Method for Scroll View 
UIScrollViewDelegate and Method

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {}
```

Function and Delegate Methods

```
// MARK:- Page Controller

func loadScrollView() {
    let pageCount : CGFloat = CGFloat(pageString.count)

    ScrollController.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    ScrollController.delegate = self
    ScrollController.isPagingEnabled = true
    ScrollController.contentSize = CGSize(width: ScrollController.frame.size.width * pageCount, height: ScrollController.frame.size.height)
    ScrollController.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    ScrollController.alwaysBounceVertical = false

    pageController.numberOfPages = Int(pageCount)
    pageController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pageChanged), for: .valueChanged)

    for i in 0..<Int(pageCount) {
        print(self.ScrollController.frame.size.width)

        let textView = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.ScrollController.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: ScreenWidth - 30 , height: 30))
        textView.text = pageString[i]
        textView.numberOfLines = 0
        textView.textColor = UIColor.white
        textView.textAlignment = .center
        self.ScrollController.addSubview(textView)
    }
}


//MARK: UIScrollView Delegate
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let viewWidth: CGFloat = scrollView.frame.size.width
    // content offset - tells by how much the scroll view has scrolled.
    let pageNumber = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - viewWidth / 50) / viewWidth) + 1
    pageController.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}


//MARK: Page tap action
@objc func pageChanged() {
    let pageNumber = pageController.currentPage
    var frame = ScrollController.frame
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(pageNumber)
    frame.origin.y = 0
    ScrollController.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true)
}
```

Finally call function in ViewDidload()

```
loadScrollView()
```